# Solve trig-equation

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

Can someone solve the equation $3\sin(x) + 2\sin^2(x) = 1$? I know that one answer is $x = 1/2\pi + k\cdot2\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ but can't seem to find the other one.

Comment: That $\;x\;$ you wrote there does **not** solve that equation you wrote, since $$3\sin\frac\pi2+2\sin^2\frac\pi2=3+2=5\neq1$$ Perhaps there's a mistake in some sign in that equation, or some where else?

Comment: Could you please show us step-by-step how you obtained your solution?

Answer (score 1):

$$2 \sin^2 x+3 \sin x-1=0$$

For a while, let $\sin x$ is $y$,

$$2y^2+3y-1=0$$
Now, $$y=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9+8}}{4}$$
$$y=\frac{-3}{4}\pm\frac{\sqrt{17}}{4}$$

Now, ignore the $-$ part because it goes out of $\sin$ range which is $\in[-1,1]$

So, you must consider $y=\frac{-3}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{17}}{4}$.

Which happens to be unsolvable in normal conventions (Not easily reducable in conventions you have written)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the old question. It was wrong; the plus sign had to be a minus sign, hence the right equation is:
$$3\sin(x)-2\sin^2(x) = 1$$

I know from Wolfram Alpha that the answers in domain $[0, 2\pi]$ are $x = \pi/2 \;\vee x= \pi/6 \; \vee x = 5\pi/6$, but how can I algebraically show this?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the new question posted in the comments:
$$3\sin{x}-2\sin^{2}{x}=1$$
Let:
$$\sin{(x)}=\beta$$
Thus:
$$-2\beta^{2}+3\beta=1$$
Dividing everything by -2
$$\beta^{2}-\frac{3}{2}\beta=-\frac{1}{2}$$
Completing the square:
$$(\beta-\frac{3}{4})^{2}=\frac{1}{16}$$
Taking the square root:
$$\beta-\frac{3}{4}=\pm\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\beta=\pm\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}$$
$$\beta=1$$
$$\beta=\frac{1}{2}$$
Solving for sin(x):
$$1=\sin{x}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}=\sin{x}$$
Recognizably the sin(90)=1, therefore, x=90. Recognizing sin(30)=.5, thus, x=30. And the reference angle of 150 is 30, and as such$$\sin{150}=\sin{30}$$ So your solutions are:

x=90

x=30

x=Any number with a reference angle of 30, or 90, which includes 150.

In radians:
$$\mathit{x}=90=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\mathit{x}=30=\frac{\pi}{6}$$